# Matlab's sparse function explanation

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

this is my first time posting anything so please be nice! 
I'm studying a code about a random walker algorithm and i got lost with the use of sparse to make the sparse laplacian matrix of a point and edge set. I'm planning to make my own code of the sparse function, but i'm having problems understanding how it works and the output of it so any help would be perfect.

Thank you all !

Comment: MATLAB's built-in help and documentation should help you here.  Entering `help sparse` or `doc sparse` will explain and give examples.  In your situation a `lookfor laplacian` will reveal the laplacian function which should be useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

A sparse matrix is a special type of "matrix" in matlab, which is conceptually equivalent to a normal matrix, but works differently 'under the hood'.

They are called "sparse", because they are usually used in situations where one would expect most elements of the matrix to contain zeros, and only a few non-zero elements.

The advantage of using this type of special object is that the memory it takes to create such an object depends primarily on the number of nonzero elements contained, rather than the size of the "actual" matrix.

By contrast, a normal (full) matrix needs memory allocated relative to its size. So for instance, a 1000x1000 matrix of numbers (so called 'doubles') will take roughly 8Mb bytes to store (1 million elements at 8 bytes per 'double'), even if all the elements are zero. Observe:

```
>> a = zeros(1000,1000);
>> b = sparse(1000,1000);
>> whos
  Name         Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1000x1000            8000000  double              
  b         1000x1000               8024  double    sparse
```

Now, assign a value to each of them at subscripts (1,1) and see what happens:

```
>> a(1,1) = 1  % without a semicolon, this will flood your screen with zeros
>> b(1,1) = 1
b =
   (1,1)        1
```

As you can see, the sparse matrix only keeps track of nonzero values, and the zeros are 'implied'.
Now lets add some more elements:

```
>> a(1:100,1:100) = 1;
>> b(1:100,1:100) = 1;
>> whos
  Name         Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1000x1000            8000000  double              
  b         1000x1000             168008  double    sparse
```

As you can see, the allocated memory for `a` hasn't changed, because the size of the overall array hasn't changed. Whereas for `b`, because it now contains more nonzero values, it takes up more space in memory.

In general most sparse matrices should work with the same operations as normal matrices; the reason for this is that most 'normal' functions are explicitly defined to also accept sparse matrices, but treat them differently under the hood (i.e. they try to arrive at the same result, but using a different approach internally to do so, one that is more suitable to sparse matrices). e.g.:

```
>> c = sum(a(:))
c =
       10000

>> d = sum(b(:))
d =
   (1,1)        1000000
```

You can 'convert' a full matrix directly to a sparse one with the `sparse` command, and a sparse matrix back to a "full" matrix with the `full` command:

```
>> sparse(c)
ans =
   (1,1)          10000

>> full(d)
ans =
     1000000
```